# Permanently Active Iframe

Tags: html, iframe

Is there any way to make an `iframe` active/selected even if the user clicks on elements that's outside of the `iframe`? I have a keyboard button press script inside the `iframe`, but it's not responding if I haven't clicked inside of it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this to set the focus every 100 milliseconds:

```
window.onload = function() {
    setInterval(function(){ document.getElementById("iframeidhere").focus(); }, 100);
};
```